# Infinispan:Cannot remove entry as key

Tags: infinispan

My log continously shows the below.I dont know what going wrong.If anyone know about this issue do reply.Thanks in advance.

```
2011-03-25 07:25:43,264 DEBUG   [ActiveMQ Session Task] -       Runtime.userCache: Cannot remove entry as key 2710188 was not found
2011-03-25 07:25:43,264 DEBUG   [ActiveMQ Session Task] -       UserRuntimeTemplate.userIdToCredentialCache: Cannot remove entry as key 2710188 was not found
2011-03-25 07:25:43,370 DEBUG   [ActiveMQ Session Task] -       Runtime.user.cachedObjectsCache: Cannot remove entry as key 2710287 was not found
2011-03-25 07:25:43,370 DEBUG   [ActiveMQ Session Task] -       Runtime.userCache: Cannot remove entry as key 2710287 was not found
2011-03-25 07:25:43,370 DEBUG   [ActiveMQ Session Task] -       UserRuntimeTemplate.userIdToCredentialCache: Cannot remove entry as key 2710287 was not found
2011-03-25 07:25:43,455 DEBUG   [ActiveMQ Session Task] -       Runtime.user.cachedObjectsCache: Cannot remove entry as key 2710286 was not found
2011-03-25 07:25:43,455 DEBUG   [ActiveMQ Session Task] -       Runtime.userCache: Cannot remove entry as key 2710286 was not found
2011-03-25 07:25:43,456 DEBUG   [ActiveMQ Session Task] -       UserRuntimeTemplate.userIdToCredentialCache: Cannot remove entry as key 2710286 was not found
2011-03-25 07:25:43,724 DEBUG   [ActiveMQ Session Task] -       Runtime.user.cachedObjectsCache: Cannot remove entry as key 2710187 was not found
2011-03-25 07:25:43,724 DEBUG   [ActiveMQ Session Task] -       Runtime.userCache: Cannot remove entry as key 2710187 was not found
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you *sure* you are using Infinispan? ;) Looks like the error message you've posted comes from Terracotta/EHCache:

http://svn.terracotta.org/fisheye/browse/TerracottaForge/tim-ehcache/trunk/tim-ehcache-1.7/src/main/java/org/terracotta/modules/ehcache/store/ClusteredStore.java?r=HEAD#l145